# Создание потока в методе класса

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Не получается создать поток thread (c++11) внутри метода класса - каждый раз ошибка компиляции:

C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0_mingw\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\functional:1505: ошибка: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of(Values_Refresher_Class*, QTableWidget*, Values_Refresher_Class*)>'
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;

C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0_mingw\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\functional:1526: ошибка: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of(Values_Refresher_Class*, QTableWidget*, Values_Refresher_Class*)>'
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)

Вот код:

```
#include <thread>

// Функция запуска потока
void Values_Refresher_Class::Start(QTableWidget *Table)
{
     // Установить флаг работы потока
     To_Work = true;
     // Задать потоку функцию
     thread Refresher_Thread = thread(&Values_Refresher_Class::Refresher_Handler, Table, this);
}

// Функция обработчика потока
void Values_Refresher_Class::Refresher_Handler(QTableWidget *Table)
{
    // Пока установлен флаг работы потока
    while(To_Work)
    {
        // Обновить список переменных
        Refresh_Values(Table);
        // Остановить поток на Refresh_Delay
        QThread::sleep(Refresher_Delay);
    }
}
```

Облазил кучу форумов и никак не могу понять в чем дело- если поток создавать в main, то все работает, но если перенести поток в класс, то сразу же все перестает работать. В чем может быть дело?

Работаю в QT Creator под MinGW. Использую не Qt-шные потоки, а стандартные, т.к. хочу научиться с ними работать

Comment: Приведите текст сообщения текстом, а не картинкой. Приведите код `Refresher_Handler`. А так на вид аргументы кажутся перепутанными, `this` должен идти первым.

Comment: @VTT Добавил, как Вы и просили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` должен идти первым из аргументов:

```
::std::thread Refresher_Thread{&Values_Refresher_Class::Refresher_Handler, this, Table};
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но можете объяснить, как это работает?

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov Не знаю, что тут объяснить. конструктор требует аргументы в таком порядке вот и все.

Answer (score 1):

Метод Refresher_Handler не статический, поэтому у него есть еще один скрытый параметр: this для которого будет вызван метод Refresher_Handler.

Либо объявите его статическим, либо добавьте дополнительный аргумент в конструктор thrread :

```
thread(&Values_Refresher_Class::Refresher_Handler, this, Table, this);
```

Comment: Не помогло. А статическим я его сделать не могу, т.к. в этом методе вызывается не статический метод